# Write to stdin of process listening for messages

Tags: bash, shell, ipc, stdin, file-descriptor

Say I start a process with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read line; do
 echo "stdin message: $line"
done < "/dev/stdin"
```

apparently this process is listening for data being to written to its stdin. How can another process write to it?

Comment: Btw.: `< "/dev/stdin"` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what the process's `stdin` is connected to. If it's a named pipe, they write to the pipe file. If it's a pseudo-tty, they write to the corresponding master device.

In most other cases, it's not generally possible.

Comment: yeah that's hella crazy - I just want to write to it from another process but I can't, gotta use a different IPC mechanism I guess

Comment: Do you happen to know if the read functionality uses polling or is it more evented?

Comment: It calls the `read()` system call, which blocks in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

With Linux: Add before your while loop:

```
echo $$
```

And in another shell, use the PID (e.g. 12345) as follows:

```
echo "hello" >/proc/12345/fd/1
```

Comment: yeah unfortunately have to support MacOS as well